# How to add stuff from src/main/webapp as classpath using maven-surfire plugin but only under test scope

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, maven-2

I am trying to write unit test for integration testing of a Spring application.

I read in the maven docs that you can add more stuff into classpath by doing something like this:

```
 <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <additionalClasspathElements>
            <additionalClasspathElement>path/to/additional/resources</additionalClasspathElement>
            <additionalClasspathElement>path/to/additional/jar</additionalClasspathElement>
            <additionalClasspathElement>path/to/csv/jar1, path/to/csv/jar2</additionalClasspathElement>
          </additionalClasspathElements>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

But I would like this to be available in test scope. Is it possible. I would really appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/

The Surefire Plugin is used during the test phase of the build lifecycle to execute the unit tests of an application.

The configuration for the sure fire plugin are only relevant for the unit tests.